Can We Whitelist Azure DevOps Organization URLs in Snowflake Network Policy
I'm trying to create a network policy in Snowflake to whitelist Azure DevOps Organization URLs. Here’s the SQL code I have so far:
CREATE NETWORK POLICY allow_specific_urls
  ALLOWED_DOMAINS_LIST = ('dev.azure.com', 'yourorganization.visualstudio.com')
  BLOCKED_DOMAINS_LIST = ();

While running a query in Snowflake from an Azure DevOps pipeline, I encountered the following error:

Incoming request with IP/Token 49.37.133.107 is not allowed to access Snowflake. Contact your account administrator.

While running a query in Snowflake from an Azure DevOps pipeline, I encountered Error.
Questions:

Is this the correct approach to whitelist Azure DevOps URLs?
Are there specific Azure DevOps URLs I should include based on different regions or services?
What else should I consider when implementing this network policy?
How can I ensure that the IP address from Azure DevOps is included in the allowed list?
I want to ensure that all requests to Azure DevOps are allowed while restricting others. Any help or examples would be greatly helpful!


I think it is not possible with the Domain allow mechanism but would need the IP range data that Azure provides and then use it to set up the network rule with IP details and then include it in the network policy.Snowflake gives option to restrict outbound connections with domain listing.
Here are the details for the Azure DevOps IP ranges: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4
This can be automated as well to ensure that the IP range updates on Azure can be updated on Snowflake as well using Python script.
